# Cmake - Test if exists pre-post build

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a `add_custom_command` and I want to make it only if a file exist. But my file is created after this line, how can I check is exist at pre or post build ?

Comment: [Build events](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) (`add_custom_command(TARGET)` command flow) are executed sequentially with given target, no file existent check is performed. If you need you command to be executed after some file is (re)created, then use [generating signature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files) of this command (`add_custom_command(OUTPUT)`).

Comment: Ok thanks @Tsyvarev